# Constructing child class using Spring without explicit casting

Tags: java, xml, spring, inheritance, javabeans

Example classes:

Animal.java

```
public class Animal {
    Animal(){
    }
}
```

Dog.java

```
public class Dog extends Animal {
    Dog(){
    }
}
```

Spring call

```
...
            // Dog dog = null; // this works
            Animal dog = null; // does not work
            ApplicationContext appContext = null;
            String path = "animal.xml";
            try
            {
                appContext = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("/" + path);
                GenericBeanFactoryAccessor gbfa = new GenericBeanFactoryAccessor(appContext);
                dog = gbfa.getBean("Dog");
                dog.init(color);
                return dog;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LOGGER.info("Bean creation failure, error is: " + e);
                return new Animal();
            }
```

animal.xml:

```
    <bean id="Animal" class="test.Animal">
    </bean>

    <bean id="Dog" class="test.Dog" parent="Animal" >
    </bean>
```

Apologies for the barebones example, but I am having an issue with this specific issue. The Dog class cannot be explicitly called in the code because it may or may not be there. I want to create the Dog class with Spring if the package exists, but just return an animal if it doesn't.

If I explicitly declare the `dog` variable as `Dog` instead of `Animal`, this code works. However, since the code might not have the `Dog` package, I cannot do this. Having the `dog` variable declared as an `Animal` gives the error when getting the ApplicationContext.

```
12 21:01:09.589 [main] INFO  - Bean creation failure, error is: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: 
Cannot find class [test.Dog] for bean with name 'Dog' defined in file [animals.xml]; 
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: test.Dog
```

Keeping in mind that everything works perfectly if `dog` is declared as `Dog` instead of `Animal`, I don't understand why I would get a class not found exception here. Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks!

Edited: Fixed lowercase dog typo

Comment: What version of spring are you using?

Comment: @paranoidAndroid 2.5

Comment: First - It doesn't reproduce on my machine, it works either way, but more importantly, what do you mean just return an Animal if it doesn't? You declare the bean as test.Dog in the XML. It means that in runtime you must have access to this class, otherwise a ClassNotFoundException will be thrown. You can't expect spring to return an Animal instance. And it doesn't matter whether you declare the variable as 'Dog' or Animal, what matters is the actual instance class. Which is test.Dog for bean 'Dog'

Comment: @paranoidAndroid Right. What I mean is, when the ClassNotFoundException is thrown, it'll create an Animal like new Animal(). This is in the catch block of the code I shown. Interesting that it worked either way for you. I'll have to keep looking it seems.

Comment: The way you declare the variable doesn't matter - internally, this is just an unchecked cast from Object to T (in getBean). If the actual type doesn't match - a ClassCastException will be thrown. This is very strange. If you post the complete code maybe I will be able to help more

Comment: @paranoidAndroid That is strange indeed. I think I have posted my exact code already (with variable/path names changed). I can't post anything more because the application is huge, but I am quite sure that this is all the relevant bits. Thanks so much for your help I will see if I can make a standalone application and test this as well.

Comment: I suspect there is some crucial and relevant part missing here, since this is very basic stuff that must work. The mere act of declaring the variable as a subclass or not - cannot in any circumstance give you a ClassNotFoundException. Basically a CNFE means that the class is not in the classpath at all, or Spring tries to load it from a wrong class loader (putting aside a misspelling of the fully qualified class name)